# How to validate time format?

Tags: python, validation, time, format

This is what I have so far, it probably is completely junk. What I want to do is validate `caminput1`, so that the format is `HH:MM:SS`.

The hashes are from when I was testing.

```
def cameraspeedcheck():
    timeformat = ("%H:%M:%S")
    caminput1 = input("At what time did sensor 1 actuate? ")

    # is caminput1 = time(HH:MM:SS)
    # time.strptime(caminput1[%H:%M:%S])

    caminput1.strptime(timeformat)
    # else cameraspeedcheck()
```

I am not very experienced with the syntax of all this stuff, or coding in general, but before you tell me to go and look it up.

I have been looking around for ages, and I cannot find anything that explains the whole process.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[`strptime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) is a class-method of `datetime.datetime` which accepts the string to parse as first argument and the format as the second argument. So you should do -

```
def cameraspeedcheck():
    timeformat = "%H:%M:%S"
    caminput1 = input("At what time did sensor 1 actuate? ")
    try:
        validtime = datetime.datetime.strptime(caminput1, timeformat)
        #Do your logic with validtime, which is a valid format
    except ValueError:
        #Do your logic for invalid format (maybe print some message?).
```

Comment: Thanks for replying so quickly! this works perfectly for my task.